# What would it take to shut down NK’s internet?

Tags: north-korea, nuclear-weapons, foreign-policy, internet

According to the South Korean govt, North Korea makes quite a bit of money of crypto mining and hacking.  If we could shut off there internet, we could make this income a lot harder to get and access, but it wouldn’t hurt the normal population like a blockade would.  How hard would it be for China to support it? (I assume they provide the internet cables to NK). What are the negatives?

Also could this help slow the nuclear weapons program?  I assume a lot of the uranium is bought from terror groups with crypto currency.

Comment: Who is "we" in "if we could shut off their internet"? Why do you think China would help? Why do you think there are only cables to China ?

Comment: Asking us to evaluate what the negatives of a policy are is probably not a great idea. The community could probably track down official statements about this policy - if any have publicly occurred. Also, please be cognizant of the fact that you are asking multiple different questions. One question per question please.

Comment: Neither mining (for which I'd love to see some evidence that NK is doing it) nor phishing/hacking needs a lot of bandwidth, so disabling the land line internet wouldn't do a lot. Also, I doubt that NK is buying uranium from some local militia in Africa and pays with bitcoins.

Comment: Negotiation with China, and since this hasn't come up seriously no one knows how hard that would be.

Comment: 1) China and SK are the only land borders with NK and I couldn't find any marine cables on a marine cable map

Comment: This is the article about mining in NK: https://www.recordedfuture.com/north-korea-internet-activity/ Just do CTRL-F and search for mining

Comment: Russia shares a [border](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Korea%E2%80%93Russia_border) with North Korea.

Comment: @IanWhitehouse You know signals can be sent through the air, right? And also that there are satellites. And that mining and hacking can be done from  places other than NK.